# How to disconnect from Firebase emulator using Android Hilt

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, dagger-hilt, firebase-tools

I am trying to use the Firebase Auth and Firestore emulator for testing, but my real Firebase app for development. I have Hilt for dependency injection. In my test module, I set `useEmulator` but in my development module, I just use the Firebase singletons. It turns out development is still using the emulator because the singleton is shared between tests and development. How do I disconnect from the emulator in the development module?

Development module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object FirebaseModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuth(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDb(): FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore
}
```

Test module:

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(components = [SingletonComponent::class], replaces = [FirebaseModule::class])
object FakeFirebaseModule {
    private val TAG = FakeFirebaseModule::class.simpleName

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuth(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth.apply {
        try {
            useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "User emulator failed", e)
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDb(): FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore.apply {
        try {
            useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080)
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "User emulator failed", e)
        }
        firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(false).build()
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@UninstallModules(FirebaseModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
@MediumTest
class ExampleTest {
    private val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    private val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @get:Rule
    val rule: TestRule = RuleChain.outerRule(hiltRule).around(composeTestRule)

    @Inject
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    @Inject
    lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(TestData.UserEmail1, TestData.UserPassword1)
            .addOnFailureListener {
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(TestData.UserEmail1, TestData.UserPassword1)
            }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sigh* I figured out what was wrong and I was looking in completely the wrong place. I thought my development code was using test data, but actually it was using stale development data. I had this in my code:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Query.getObjectsFlow() = callbackFlow {
    val subscription = addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        when {
            error != null -> cancel("Get snapshot failed", error)
            value != null -> trySend(value.toObjects<T>())
        }
    }

    awaitClose { subscription.remove() }
}
```

used like this:

```
// Repository

val feed = db.collection(FEED_COLLECTION)
            .getObjectsFlow<FeedItemDocument>()
            .map { docs ->
                val feedItems = docs.map { FeedItemState.fromDocument(it) }
                if (feedItems.isEmpty()) {
                    LoadState.Empty()
                } else {
                    LoadState.Data(Feed(feedItems))
                }
            }
            .catch {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error querying server", it)
                emit(LoadState.Failure(it))
            }

// FeedItemState

data class FeedItemState(
    val id: String = "",
    val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now(),
    val text: String = "",
) {
    companion object {
        fun fromDocument(doc: FeedItemDocument): FeedItemState {
            val id = doc.id!!
            val createdAt = doc.createdAt?.toDate()?.toInstant()!!
            val text = doc.text!!
            return FeedItemState(type, id, createdAt, text)
        }
    }
}
```

My repository would emit a load failure value if any of the document fields were null. However, the snapshot listener emits every single query object including old ones. Which means when I would add fields to the database, the first object emitted would not have the new field, thus throwing an NPE.

I had to change the repository to accept and ignore null fields. So changing `docs.map { FeedItemState.fromDocument(it) }` to `mapNotNull` and allowing the `fromDocument` method to return null when the fields were null instead of using `!!`.

Lesson learned: In Kotlin if you're using `!!`, be very suspicious of the code. It can often be replaced with something that doesn't throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a disconnect feature for the emulator (Firestore) and the fields are private when connecting. See [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/cdd104464970122eeef1ae450a5d5d703a0a942f/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.java#L234).

In that case, removing the @Singleton to get different Firestore instances, or scoping the singleton to the different (test vs prod) environments will keep the production Firestore from connecting to the emulator.

Comment: I removed `@Singleton` and changed `SingletonComponent` to `ViewModelComponent`. I'm still running into the same problem.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out what was wrong and it was way out of left field